# How Disable dailymotion android SDK auto play for video?

Tags: dailymotion-api

first code sample is from activity.xml.

```
<com.dailymotion.android.player.sdk.PlayerWebView
 android:id="@+id/daily_motion_player"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="200dp"
 app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
</com.dailymotion.android.player.sdk.PlayerWebView>
```

second code sample from activity.kt.

```
fun dailymotionVideoLoad(pWebView: @NotNull PlayerWebView, video_id: String){
  val params = mapOf(
    "video" to video_id,
    "ui-highlight" to "fff",
    "logo" to "false")
  pWebView.load(params);
}
```

dailymotion video play automatically on dailymotion playerweb view how stop it.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the video to play automatically, you can use the "autoplay" parameter set to false ([full list of parameters you can use](https://developer.dailymotion.com/player/#player-parameters) )

```
fun dailymotionVideoLoad(pWebView: @NotNull PlayerWebView, video_id: String){
  val params = mapOf(
    "video" to video_id,
    "autoplay" to "false",
    "ui-highlight" to "fff",
    "logo" to "false")
  pWebView.load(params);
}
```